# Not able to view draft content in Drupal 7 site

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, ckeditor

I want to be able to see any edits I make to a field in the ckeditor when the page is in draft form without having to publish my changes first. How would I go about doing this? I thought I was in the right place by navigating to...

*Configuration -> Workbench Moderation -> Check Permissions -> (selecting the content type I want affected and selecting) check permissions button -> View moderation permissions for this role.*

This brings up a long menu with checkboxes for permissions, of which I selected "*'my content type'*: view any unpublished content", as well as the broader options "view own unpublished content" and "view content revisions" for good measure. Even though those sound like exactly what I'm after, I was sad to see that this didn't seem to affect anything, and therefore I'm still seeing original field content on an unpublished page.

Is what I'm after an option in Drupal 7? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create node revisions for the same. Suppose you created a node, keep that in unpublished mode and there you will see a checkbox on node edit page i.e "Create New Revision". You will find this information in "revision information" tab at bottom of node edit page. So, you will be able to see all those revisions of your node for which you selected create new revision while edited content/node.

Thank You!!